# How fix this?: if (!options.algorithms) throw new Error('algorithms should be set'); Error: algorithms should be set

Tags: node.js, algorithm, express-jwt

I'm learning about MERN through of PACKT platform (https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Full-Stack-React-Projects-Second-Edition/tree/master/Chapter03%20and%2004/mern-skeleton) but I can't run the code because I find the next error:

```
if (!options.algorithms) throw new Error('algorithms should be set');
        
Error: algorithms should be set
    at module.exports (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:22:34)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/controllers/auth.controller.js?:65:73)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/controllers/auth.controller.js?:111:30)
    at Module../server/controllers/auth.controller.js (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:312:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/routes/user.routes.js?:5:86)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/routes/user.routes.js?:43:30)
    at Module../server/routes/user.routes.js (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:396:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:17:77)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:133:30)
    at Module../server/express.js (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:348:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/server.js?:3:66)
    at Module../server/server.js (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:408:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/npalaciosv/Documents/Full Stack React Projects/Mern_Projects/Chapter3/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've read about this topic in other similar publication and find the solution is fix this code:

```js
expressJwt({ secret:  process.env.JWT_SECRET, algorithms: ['RS256'] })
```

Responded by @Tugay İlik

But I don't know, exactly, where do I have to add this code?

Answer (score 3):

I have checked your files. Kindly go to "server" folder, => "controllers" folder => "auth.controller.js" file; Then scroll down, from line 55-58, you'll see"

```
const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: config.jwtSecret,
  userProperty: 'auth'
})
```

Change it with:

```
const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: config.jwtSecret,
  userProperty: 'auth',
  algorithms: ['HS256'],
});
```

Please kindly let me know if it works. All the best.